# Receive files/images from user of a Skype chatbot Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Chatbot need to get files from the user (from Skype channel) and then save it into database

I haven't find any sample code or any document related to this requirement.

I have found out the this could be achieved using events. e.g. whenever user upload a file, treat it as a events and then trigger the intent and do the coding in fulfillment as per the requirement.

In case of facebook messenger, there is events "FACEBOOK_MEDIA", but what should I use in skype channel.

Comment: if you are using skype bot webhook you will receive `attachments` in your payload

Comment: Hi Nikhil,

Thank you for your comment.

I have started practicing chatbot development using Dialogflow.

Could you please share any sample code or any link where I can read about the same. It would be of great help to me.

Comment: If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here